# Get specific value from api response

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to get specific value of the response data how i can get it.In this case I need the value of ApimId.

[image]

It Shows error after update

### code

approvalPendingRequest(id) {

```
var result = this.http.get('https://localhost:44300/api/apis/GetSubscriptionById/'+ id)
    .subscribe(
    data => this._data = data.json(),
    err => this.logError(result),
    () => console.log('getsubscription api call')
);
```

}

### image

[image]

Comment: `.subscribe((result)=>this.id=result.ApimId)...`

Answer (score 2):

ApimId is a property on the response data item -- you can just use it from within code; assuming the entire response is above (ie, just one item, not an array), use:

```
result.ApimId
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access it by name from the received data:

```
this.http.get('http://...')
         .map(res => res.json()
         .subscribe((data) => {
           this.data = data;
           console.log('ApimId = '+data.ApimId);
         });
```

If you want to display it in your template, don't forget to use the Elvis operator (`?`) since your data is loaded asynchronously:

```
{{data?.ApimId}}
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting a response use the below code.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(_response.Content); 

string  ApimID= obj.ApimId;
```

Comment: The question regards typescript and angular. This seems an answer in C# or Java.